# Unknown element <select> in SQL statement MyBatis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

I am trying the functionality like saveOrUpdate with MyBatis, but I am getting the exception while deployment. Below is the query

```
@Select("<script>"
            + "<foreach item='item' index='index' collection='machineList'>"
            + "<select id='count' resultType='int'>"
            + "Select count(*) from nc_macine_data where (machine_id=#{item.machineId} and machine_name=#{item.machineName} and mchine_value=#{item.machineValue})"
            + "</select>"
            + "<if test='count > 0'>" + 
            "    UPDATE nc_macine_data set mchine_value=#{item.machineValue} where (machine_id=#{item.machineId} and machine_name=#{item.machineName}"
            + "</if>"
            + "<if test='count==0'>"
            + " INSERT INTO nc_macine_data (machine_id, machine_name, mchine_value) values (#{element.machineId}, #{element.machineName}, #{element.machineValue})"
            + "</if>"
            + "</foreach>"
            + "</script>")
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Could not find value method on SQL annotation.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Unknown element <select> in SQL statement.
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

In the example you are implicitly assuming that `foreach`, `select`, `if` and `update` are commands that are executed from top to bottom. And this is not the case.

The elements in `<script>` are very much like definitions in xml mapper. They are not a part of an imperative language like you are trying to use them.

The code tries to use `select` to "define" a variable that it tries to use later in `if` and this is exactly what does not work.

Back to the original problem. What you are trying to do is called upsert and this is [inherently hard problem](https://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/) and the naive approach to check and update or insert will not work correctly.

Different DBs provide different means to do upserts: [postgres solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql), [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists), [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606).